# How to change orientation of a tikzpicture \newcommand

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to modify a `\newcommand` using `tikzpicture` which currently renders bubbles horizontally, in order to arrange the bubbles vertically aligned with their texts next to each of them.
here is the latex:

```
\newcommand{\bubbles}[1]{
% Reset counters
\setcounter{a}{0}
\setcounter{c}{150}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
    \foreach \p/\t in {#1} {
        \addtocounter{a}{1}
        \bubble{\thea/2}{\theb}{\p/25}{\t}{1\p0}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

% Command to output a bubble at a specific position with a specific size
\newcommand{\bubble}[5]{
    \filldraw[fill=black, draw=none] (#1,0.5) circle (#3); % Bubble
    \node[label=\textcolor{black}{#4}] at (#1,0.7) {}; % Label
}
```

Is there any way i could do this?

Comment: Welcome! You essentially need to swap the horizontal and vertical coordinates, ` \filldraw[fill=black, draw=none] (0,1-#1) circle (#3); 
    \node[label=\textcolor{black}{#4}] at (0.2,1-#1) {};`. But there are many things is do not understand with this code, they seem to be unnecessary. Could you please provide us with a complete minimal compilable example that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and shows how you use these commands?

Comment: yes sure! `\begin{center} 
 \bubbles{5/\textsc{item1}, 3/\textsc{item2}, 6/\textsc{item3}, 5/\textsc{item4}, 5/\textsc{item5}, 4/\textsc{item6}, 5/\textsc{item7}}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}`

Comment: also thank you for the suggestion it did make the bubbles vertically rendered. but now i have another problem i cant align this bubbles command as a minipage next to another minipage that is already in the document modifying the begin and end statements as this  `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth} \end{minipage}`

Comment: Please add a complete compilable document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. Add it to the question (rather to the comments).